# How to pass a variable value in exec_command in python?

Tags: python-3.x, paramiko

I have declared a value for a variable command as

```
command =4
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("pwd; ./test.sh command")
```

when i try to run the above command it show the output as

```
I am command
```

but it should return as

```
I am 4
```

Any syntax missing in the above command?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing "command" as the string, but you need to pass its value as a string:

```
ssh.exec_command("pwd; ./test.sh " + str(command))
```

Comment: I used the above command, Now only pwd is executing bypassing theother commands and the output is as

Input:- ssh.exec_command("pwd; ./test.sh" + str(command))

Output:- ['/home/ubuntu\n']

Comment: What is in `stderr` after you execute that?

Comment: Thank you john!! This solved the problem. There was no space between those two commands.